# How to make Shift + Enter behave like Enter inside a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a component that uses a contenteditable `div`.

**NOTE1:** This was tested only on Chrome.
**NOTE2:** I cannot use jQuery.

The default behaviour when pressing Enter is to add a new `<div><br><div>`

But when you press `Shift + Enter` it adds only a `<br>` inside the current `div`.

How can I make `Shift + Enter` behave like `Enter`?

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById('root');


function handleInput() {
  console.log('Div innerHTML: ' + myDiv.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
#root {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the div below and press Enter and Shift+Enter to see the difference</p>

<div 
  id="root" 
  contenteditable
  onInput="handleInput()"
>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that Safari _does_ insert a `<div><br></div>` with `⇧ + ↵`, and inserts the `<br>` only with `⌃ + ↵`. Chrome doesn't do any input with `⌃ + ↵`.

Comment: Thanks. But what do you mean by `⌃ + ↵` ?

Comment: `Control` + `Enter`

Comment: @JacobFord that's the same `control` and `shift` key for windows, right? Does `command` enter do something? Thanks!

Comment: Just checked! `⌘ + ↵` does nothing in your `contenteditable` field on macOS, in both Safari and Chrome. I haven't checked if `ctrl + Enter` does the forced line break on Windows.

Comment: @JacobFord thanks! `ctrl + Enter` did nothing on Windows / Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

```js
myDiv.onkeypress = function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13 && evt.shiftKey) {
        // Shift + enter pressed
        evt.preventDefault()
        evt.stopPropagation() // Stop default handling

        // Simulate enter is pressed
        var e = new Event("keydown");
        e.keyCode = 13;
        e.which = e.keyCode;
        myDiv.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711383/how-to-make-shift-enter-behave-like-enter-inside-a-contenteditable-div#comment98103948_55711383) you'll probably also want to check for `ctrlKey`, as this is what Safari uses to type a forced line break.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Could you add that into the snippet I created? Thanks!

Comment: For me this only captures the event once, and also still inserts a plain <br>.

Comment: @cbdeveloper have you found any solution?